# How to directly query other user tables

Tags: oracle, restore

I am trying to learn Oracle database and I am having difficulties on importing a backup file with impdp command. I googled deeply but couldn't find answers to my problems. What have I done until now is:

1. I created a user as Test1 with tablespace
2. I granted some privileges through sqlplus
3. I imported the backup file by using impdp command with options fromuser=Test2 touser=Test1
4. I imported the backup file by using impdp command with options fromuser=Test2 touser=Test1
5. I started sqldeveloper and connected to Test1
6. I expanded tables but there is no table to be displayed
7. I expanded other users. There is also another Test1 among other users
8. I checked tables of Test1 and the tables were all there

Now my questions:

1. Although I chose touser=Test1 option, why the tables are displayed in Test1 which is in other users group? I expected the tables to be in first users' table list
2. How can I import database directly to the user I created? I don't want to use other users because I have to use [schema_name].[table_name] in my selects which is a waste of time for me.
3. I can click on tables in other user table list and display the data but I cannot open a blank sql page to write some queries. Is there any way to do that?

EDIT:

The command I used when importing is:

```
impdp Test1/123 DIRECTORY=backup_dir DUMPFILE=Test.dmp FULL=Y fromuser=Test2 touser=Test1
```

The result is as follows:

[image: User and Other Users tables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case somebody else needs, I am posting the solution I used. Instead of using `fromuser` and `touser` options, I used `remap_schema` option:

```
> impdp user1/password DIRECTORY=backup_dir DUMPFILE=Dump.dmp FULL=Y
> remap_schema=user2:user1
```

Also, if the tablespaces are different, they must be remapped, too:

```
> impdp user1/password DIRECTORY=backup_dir DUMPFILE=Dump.dmp FULL=Y
> remap_schema=user2:user1 remap_tablespace=table2:table1
```